# Doing a join between excel tables/sheets in Python Pandas, why do all of the entries in one particular column have the same values after the join?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two excel docs:

invasive_plants_in_and_around_park_with_compared_and_with_habitat_data_hand_edited.xlsx
-with 3 sheets "Species_only_at_park", "Species_only_outside_park", and "Species_present_both"

the other doc is

priority_lists_by_visibility_months_hand_edited2.xlsx

- with 3 sheets "Spring_Search", "missing_visibility_data", "only_visible_outside_spring"

invasive(etc).xlsx has a column "Presence" that I just edited so that it is labeled based on the sheet the entry is in. (Presence="only at park" for all the entries in the sheet "Species_only_at_park" and so on).

However, after running my code, ALL entries in my output excel doc have Presence="in and around Park". What might be causing this, how can I troubleshoot/fix this?

````
import pandas as pd

# Read the first Excel file with multiple sheets
park_file = pd.ExcelFile("python generated excel files/invasive_plants_in_and_around_park_with_compared_and_with_habitat_data_hand_edited.xlsx")

# Read all sheets from the first Excel file
park_sheets = ["Species_only_at_park", "Species_only_outside_park", "Species_present_both"]
park_dfs = {sheet: park_file.parse(sheet) for sheet in park_sheets}

# Read the second Excel file with multiple sheets
priority_file = pd.ExcelFile("python generated excel files/priority_lists_by_visibility_months_hand_edited2.xlsx")

# Read all sheets from the second Excel file
priority_sheets = ["Spring_Search", "missing_visibility_data","only_visible_outside_spring"]
priority_dfs = {sheet: priority_file.parse(sheet) for sheet in priority_sheets}

# Define the new column order
common_columns = ['rank', 'Species', 'Common names', 'Presence', 'location', 'Concatenated',
             'Important', 'notes', 'rating', 'Cal IPC rating', 'CDFA', 'Hort', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'U',
             'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October',
             'November', 'December']

# Perform join on the two DataFrames based on the "Species" column
final_dfs = {}
for priority_sheet, priority_df in priority_dfs.items():
    # Perform join
    final_df = pd.merge(park_dfs['Species_only_at_park'], priority_df, on="Species", how="left", suffixes=('_park', '_priority'))
    
    # Update columns and store the final DataFrame
    final_df.rename(columns={'Concatenated': 'all possible habitats'}, inplace=True)
    final_df = final_df.reindex(columns=common_columns)
    final_dfs[priority_sheet] = final_df

# Perform join on the two DataFrames based on the "Species" column
for priority_sheet, priority_df in priority_dfs.items():
    # Perform join
    final_df = pd.merge(park_dfs['Species_only_outside_park'], priority_df, on="Species", how="left", suffixes=('_park', '_priority'))
    
    # Update columns and store the final DataFrame
    final_df.rename(columns={'Concatenated': 'all possible habitats'}, inplace=True)
    final_df = final_df.reindex(columns=common_columns)
    final_dfs[priority_sheet] = final_df

# Perform join on the two DataFrames based on the "Species" column
for priority_sheet, priority_df in priority_dfs.items():
    # Perform join
    final_df = pd.merge(mgp_dfs['Species_present_both'], priority_df, on="Species", how="left", suffixes=('_park', '_priority'))
   
    # Update columns and store the final DataFrame
    final_df.rename(columns={'Concatenated': 'all possible habitats'}, inplace=True)
    final_df = final_df.reindex(columns=common_columns)
    final_dfs[priority_sheet] = final_df

# Write the final DataFrames to an Excel file with two sheets
with pd.ExcelWriter("FINAL_invasive_species_watchlist6.xlsx") as writer:
    for priority_sheet, final_df in final_dfs.items():
        final_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=priority_sheet, index=False)




```
````

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset from these sheets?